# How to remove some pages from the navigation bullets in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, navigation, mini-frames

I'm making a `beamer` presentation using the `miniframes` outer theme, with navigation bullets, and the `subsection=false` option, meaning the bullets are all on a single row. The problem I have is that, if one section has too many pages, the bullets overflow to the next section:

```
Section 1 Section 2
oooooooooooooooooooo
```

I tend to have many frames, some of them just asking a question, leading to the next detailed frame. I don't really need those frames to be represented by navigation bullets, and removing them would fix the problem. Any idea how to do that?

I could cheat by using overlays to have the question and the answer on the same frame, but that would be a mess...

Code example to answer percusse's question: this should give you one circle per frame, not one per subsection. If you add many frames in one subsection, the circles will overflow over the next section.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\begin{document}
\section{S1}
\subsection{SS1}
\frame{1}
\frame{2}
\frame{3}
\subsection{SS2}
\frame{1}
\frame{2}
\frame{3}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am still trying to get the problem. When I put everything inside a subsection there is no circle added due to the frames. I get only one circle per subsection and the frame number doesn't change it. Can you include a small compilable MWE?

Comment: I edited the question to include an example

Answer (score 49):

The mini frames are generated using the `\beamer@framepages` entries in the auxiliary `.nav` file. If you remove these for certain frames, they don't appear in the navigation<sup>1</sup>. To do so, you have to patch the `\beamer@writeslidentry` macro responsible for writing the commands to the `.nav` file:

```
\makeatletter
\let\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson=\beamer@writeslidentry
\def\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff{%
  \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
  {%else
    % removed \addtocontents commands
    \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
  }
}
\newcommand*{\miniframeson}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson}
\newcommand*{\miniframesoff}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff}
\makeatother
```

Include this code in your document, then you can switch between the original implementation and the modified one not generating any mini frames by using `\miniframeson` and `\miniframesoff`.

<sup>1</sup>This may, however, have some unwanted consequences I'm not aware of!

#### Full example code:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\makeatletter
\let\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson=\beamer@writeslidentry
\def\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff{%
  \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
  {%else
    % removed \addtocontents commands
    \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
  }
}
\newcommand*{\miniframeson}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson}
\newcommand*{\miniframesoff}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{S1}
\subsection{SS1}
\frame{1}
\miniframesoff
\frame{2}
\miniframeson
\frame{3}
\subsection{SS2}
\miniframesoff
\frame{1}
\miniframeson
\frame{2}
\frame{3}
\end{document}
```

#### Resulting headline (only four of six mini frames are displayed):

[image: headline produced by the example code, showing only four (of originally six) mini frames]

Comment: Note that this only works when you enable the compress option. Otherwise, the miniframes will still take up space.

Comment: @TimvanDalen, what do you mean that the miniframes will still take up space? I tried it without the compress option and it seemed to work fine for me.

Comment: One small issue with this approach is that the navigation bullets are all empty/open (similar to the appearance on a title slide that is inserted before the first section). It would have been nice if the last 'active' bullet would remain filled until the bullets are switched back on.

Comment: Does this work with other outer themes such as `smoothbars`?