# Hide frame's dot from the slide heading in beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, navigation, mini-frames

Please i want to add some frames to my beamer presentation but without adding a new dot in the frame heading.

There's any method to do that ?
Below is a minimum code example with the theme i am using.

Thanks for your help

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{Darmstadt}
    \usecolortheme{seahorse}

    \begin{document}
    \section{title 1}

    \subsection{title 2}

    \begin{frame}{Title (I)}
              Show the corresponding dot (circle) above
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Title (II)}
     Hide the corresponding dot (circle) above
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37127/how-to-remove-some-pages-from-the-navigation-bullets-in-beamer)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @dcmst well done! I knew this had been asked and answered before, but couldn't find the exact link.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I'm very familiar with the code in there, helped me a lot, so I knew where to look :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use overlays:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\begin{document}
\section{title 1}

\subsection{title 2}

\begin{frame}{\only<1>{Title (I) --- first dot}\only<2>{Title (II) --- still first dot}}
    \only<1>{Content (I)}
    \only<2>{Content (II)}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title (III) --- second dot}
    Content (III)
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But this doesn't hide the miniframe from appearing in the headline, and that's what the OP is requesting.