# Making a specific dot disappear in miniframes

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

I am using the beamer template `miniframes` with the following specifications:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false,shadow]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
\usefonttheme{serif}
```

One aspect is, there are dots at the top of the page in the header, one dot corresponding to  every frame. As I progress through this, the active dot keeps moving along (I'm sure most readers must have seen this template).

Is there any way to prevent one specific frame from appearing amongst the dots? 
I.e. all others are as usual, just one specific frame doesn't show up there.

`{frame}*` doesn't seem to be working.

Any work-arounds?

Comment: take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37127/how-to-remove-some-pages-from-the-navigation-bullets-in-beamer