# Beamer Singapore

Tags: beamer

I having a problem with the bullets points that appears on the header of the Singapore theme.  Before, it didn't add a bullet point for the outline page when using

```
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}{Outline}
  \small \tableofcontents[currentsection, hideothersubsections]
  \end{frame} 
}
```

Now I have an extra bullet each time I change a section... does anybody knows how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 4):

Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45038/36296 you could do:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{Singapore}

\AtBeginSection[]{
    \miniframesoff%
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \small \tableofcontents[currentsection, hideothersubsections]
  \end{frame} 
  \miniframeson%
}


\makeatletter
\let\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson=\beamer@writeslidentry%
\def\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff{%
  \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
  {%else
    % removed \addtocontents commands
    \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
  }
}
\newcommand*{\miniframeson}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson}
\newcommand*{\miniframesoff}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{sd}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does do not solve the problem, because I want to maintain the bullets points in different lines for each subsection...

Comment: @A.Vero Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: \documentclass[slidetop]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{etex}
\usetheme{Singapore}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 1}}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 2}}


\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 1}}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 2}}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 3}}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 4}}

\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 1}}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 2}}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 3}}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 4}}


\end{document}