# How not to show subsections in beamer progress bar

Tags: beamer

Consider the following reproducible example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

%% Main theme.
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

%% Beamer template.
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][left] % Slides' titles on left.
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number] % Numbering slides.
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[circle] % Customizing ToC.
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % Hiding navigation bar.

\begin{document}

%% ToC.
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection, subsectionstyle = show/show/hide]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[hidesubsections]
\end{frame}

%% Section 1.
\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}{One frame} % THIS SHOWN!
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{One frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{1.A}
\begin{frame}{One frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The following picture shows the first frame (the one flagged in the code above):

[image]

I would like to solve two issues. 1) Is it possible not to show subsections in the top progress bar? For instance, in the picture, I have two rows of bullets in the progress bar, the lower indicating subsection 1.A. Can I impose one row only, basically ignoring subsections? 2) The table of contents, shown at the beginning of each sextion, enters the progress bar as the first bullet of each section. Is it possible to avoid that?

**EDIT**

I solved the second issue, namely removing the table of contents' frames from the progress bar. Thanks to @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, who answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414525/beamer-singapore) (I know the tag is not valid).

Comment: I think you are not supposed to combine two questions/issues together like this. But I want to know the answer to your first issue. I would post a new question, or heavily edit this one now that your 2nd issue is solved, so that only the first issue is mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `compress` class option to show all miniframes in one line:

```
\documentclass[11pt,compress]{beamer}

%% Main theme.
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

%% Beamer template.
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][left] % Slides' titles on left.
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number] % Numbering slides.
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[circle] % Customizing ToC.
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % Hiding navigation bar.

\begin{document}

%% ToC.
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection, subsectionstyle = show/show/hide]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[hidesubsections]
\end{frame}

%% Section 1.
\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}{One frame} % THIS SHOWN!
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{One frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{1.A}
\begin{frame}{One frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```