# Beamer - Colouring Specific Navigation Circles

Tags: beamer, highlighting, circles, navigation, bullets

I have some frames that are just small increments from previous frames and, as such, I do not wish them to have a distinct navigation circle. I've been able to achieve this by using the method described in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45038), which consists of:

```
\makeatletter
    \let\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson=\beamer@writeslidentry
    \def\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff{%
        \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
        {%else
            % removed \addtocontents commands
            \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
        }
    }
    \newcommand*{\miniframeson}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson}
    \newcommand*{\miniframesoff}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff}
    \beamer@compresstrue
\makeatother
```

However, by surpressing the navigation circle in those incremental frames, now the corresponding slides have no highlighted navigation bullet, like this:[image]

Instead of the usual case (i.e., for non-surpressed navigation circles), which is like this:[image]

Now, since these incremental frames for which I'm surpressing the navigation bullets are essentially the same, I would like the navigation bullet associated to the first frame (of the "incremental group") to remain highlighted.

Is there a way to achieve this directly?

Or, alternatively, is there a way to highlight a specific navigation circle?

This can be observed on the MWE, on slides title 4 and title 5 (exemplified here only on 4):
[image]

My idea was to have both slides title 4 and 5 highlight the first navigation circle of section 2, like this:

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table,xcdraw},compress]{beamer}

% Beamer's Slide numbers
\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\large}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{% 
  \hfill% 
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}% 
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}% 
  \insertframenumber%
  %\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber
  \kern1em\vskip2pt% 
}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx, color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%% Load the markdown package
\usepackage[footnotes,definitionLists,hashEnumerators,smartEllipses,tightLists=false,pipeTables,tableCaptions,hybrid]{markdown}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bm} % Bold math symbols
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xmpmulti}


\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usecolortheme{whale}


% Remove navigation bullets
\makeatletter
    \let\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson=\beamer@writeslidentry
    \def\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff{%
        \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
        {%else
            % removed \addtocontents commands
            \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
        }
    }
    \newcommand*{\miniframeson}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson}
    \newcommand*{\miniframesoff}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff}
    \beamer@compresstrue
\makeatother




\begin{document}

\section{sec1}
\subsection{subsec1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title2}
\end{frame}

\section{sec2}
\subsection{subsec2}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title3}
\end{frame}

\miniframesoff
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title4}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title5}
\end{frame}

\miniframeson
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title6}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal working example (MWE) showing your current document setup.

Comment: Sorry for the omission. I've now added it.