# How to remove a specific frame from navigation bullets?

Tags: beamer

I would like to disable a specific section or a frame from appearing among the navigation bullets in the headline. How could it be done?

I am aware of this Q&A https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45038/81639, but I am reported an `Option clash for package beamerouterthememiniframes`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}
    \section{Sec1}
    \begin{frame}
        Fr1
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        Fr2
    \end{frame}
\section{Sec2}
    \begin{frame}
        Fr3
    \end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    This frame should not appear among the navigation bullets
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why don't you use the obvious idea to simply remove the `\section*{NoSec}`?

Comment: You are right, I removed `\section*`. However, the question remains: how to disable the frame appearing among the bullets (see edit)

Comment: You could probably add `\begingroup\makeatletter\let\beamer@writeslidentry\relax` ... `\endgroup` around the frame.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you, this solves the question. If you make it an answer, I'd be happy to accept it

Comment: The verbatim and aeb-comment packages support a comment environment.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments

Comment: It is perhaps good to note that the the solution proposed in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530274/how-to-remove-a-specific-frame-from-navigation-bullets#comment1340954_530274) does still leave an empty spot where a navigation bullet would otherwise be placed, which may not be desirable. `\makeatother` should probably also have been added after `\relax`.

Comment: Exactly why this question is considered off-topic?

Comment: People sometimes vote to close questions that were answered in the comments as 'off-topic'. (In the old days questions that were only due to small typos were often 'answered' in the comments and then closed as 'too localized'. That close reason does not exist any more, so people sometimes select 'off-topic' as replacement.) In case the answer in the comments is more than just a typo or a simple misunderstanding I find that closing as 'off-topic' isn't quite the right thing to do. That seems to be the case here. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to type up an answer here in case the question is reopened.

Comment: Replace the `\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}` in the linked duplicate with your `\usetheme{Berlin}` to avoid the option clash