# Background image on frame not in slide navigation

Tags: beamer, backgrounds, grouping

I try to achieve the following: have a background image on a frame and disable the frame to appear in the navigation bullets at the same time. I can do both but not at the same time.
If commenting out `\begingroup...` and `\endgroup`, the image is shown, but the frame is in the navigation bullets, else the image is not seen.
I also tried to change the place of the group and the curly braces around the frame.

A strange thing is that when I comment out the group delimiters, running pdflatex first will give a good result, but after a new compilation it's wrong:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}
    \section{Sec1}
    \begin{frame}
        Fr1
    \end{frame}


{\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\vskip\headheight}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
    \includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image}
}
\begingroup\makeatletter\let\beamer@writeslidentry\relax
    \begin{frame}
        This frame should not appear among the navigation bullets and the background image should be seen
    \end{frame}
\endgroup
}

\end{document}
```

With group delimiters:

[image]

With commenting out group delimiters:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [How to remove some pages from the navigation bullets in Beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37127/how-to-remove-some-pages-from-the-navigation-bullets-in-beamer) the bullet is removed and the image is displayed. However, this causes the slide counter to increase, and therefore the bullet for the next normal slide will be placed after a gap:

[image]

To fix this you can decrease the slide counter manually.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}
    \section{Sec1}
    \begin{frame}
        Fr1
    \end{frame}


{\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image}}
\makeatletter
% suppress bullet in navigation
\def\beamer@writeslidentry{\clearpage\beamer@notesactions}
% decrease slide counter manually
\advance\c@subsectionslide -1\relax
\makeatother
% [plain] switches off headline and footline
\begin{frame}[plain]
        This frame should not appear among the navigation bullets and the background image should be seen
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
        Fr2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note: further side effects may occur, so check the output carefully.