# Headline in Beamer

Tags: beamer, headline

I am making a presentation in beamer and need your help dealing the headline.

I include a headline with the 4 fours sections, with dots representing each slide. However, I would like to "hide" one of the sections, that is, to keep the section and the slide, but hide it in the headline.

Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [How to remove some pages from the navigation bullets in Beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37127/134144) seems to be related.

Comment: duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578110/adding-a-section-to-beamer-table-of-contents-but-not-to-navigation-bar