# Adding a section to beamer table of contents but not to navigation bar

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning, navigation

I want to have all of my sections in a beamer presentation shown in the table of contents, but only some of them shown in the upper navigation bar (in the example below, the last two sections, "Three" and "Four", should be shown only in the table of contents). I've tried the second solution described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154965/163378. The result is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\addsectiontotoc[1]{%
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\beamer@sectionintoc{\the\c@section}{#1}{\the\c@page}{\the\c@part}%
    {\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{One}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Two}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\addsectiontotoc{Three}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\addsectiontotoc{Four}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, there are two problem here. First, sections "Three" and "Four" both have number "2", whereas I would like them to have numbers "3" and "4", respectively. Second, I would like to have no dots corresponding to slides under the sections "Three" and "Four" in the navigation bar, whereas now there are dots corresponding to them, which are associated with section "Two". Is there any way to modify this example in the way satisfying my expectations?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a section with an empty optional argument to remove it from the headline navigation, e.g. `\section[]{three}`.

And to hide the miniframes, you can switch them off like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}


\makeatletter
\let\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson=\beamer@writeslidentry%
\def\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff{%
  \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
  {%else
    % removed \addtocontents commands
    \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
  }
}
\newcommand*{\miniframeson}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson}
\newcommand*{\miniframesoff}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{One}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Two}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\miniframesoff 

\section[]{three}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section[]{four}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```