# Removing sectionpage bullet from navigation bar - beamer-Metropolis

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I want to have sectionpages (`sectionpage = progressbar`) in my slides. However, I don't want them to appear in the navigation bar. Is there any way to do it? Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames},compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usetheme[titleformat=regular, numbering=fraction, progressbar=frametitle, background=light, sectionpage=progressbar]{metropolis}           % Use metropolis theme

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}


\title{A minimal example}
\date{\today}
\author{John Smith}
\institute{School of something, The University of World}



%----------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \begin{frame}{Overview}
    \tableofcontents
  \end{frame}
   
  \section{First Section}
  \begin{frame}{First Frame}
    Hello, world!
  \end{frame}

  \section{Second Section}
  \begin{frame}{Second Frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item option 1
        \item option 2
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}

  \section{Third Section}
  \begin{frame}{Third Frame}
  \only<1-2>{ % this allows to have multiple frames with only one bullet that is highlighted
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item option 1
        \item option 2
    \end{enumerate}
    \pause
  
    \begin{equation}
        f(x)=a\times x^2+b\times x +c
    \end{equation}
    }
  \end{frame}
  
 

  % Thank you slide
  \begin{frame}[standout]
    Thank you!
  \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Currently, this is what I see. While I only have one frame in the section, you can see two bullets in the navigation bar, the first one is for sectionpage:
[image]

This is the same for other sectionpages too. Any thought on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the same trick as in [How to remove some pages from the navigation bullets in Beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37127/how-to-remove-some-pages-from-the-navigation-bullets-in-beamer/45038#45038)

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames},compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle, background=light, sectionpage=progressbar]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}


\title{A minimal example}
\date{\today}
\author{John Smith}
\institute{School of something, The University of World}

\makeatletter
\let\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson=\beamer@writeslidentry%
\def\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff{%
  \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
  {%else
    % removed \addtocontents commands
    \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
  }
}
\newcommand*{\miniframeson}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson}
\newcommand*{\miniframesoff}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff}


\renewcommand{\moloch@enablesectionpage}{
  \AtBeginSection{
  \miniframesoff
    \ifbeamer@inframe
      \sectionpage
    \else
      \frame[plain,c,noframenumbering]{\sectionpage}
    \fi
  \miniframeson
  }
}
\moloch@enablesectionpage
\makeatother

%----------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \begin{frame}{Overview}
    \tableofcontents
  \end{frame}
   
  \section{First Section}
  \begin{frame}{First Frame}
    Hello, world!
  \end{frame}

  \section{Second Section}
  \begin{frame}{Second Frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item option 1
        \item option 2
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}

  \section{Third Section}
  \begin{frame}{Third Frame}
  \only<1-2>{ % this allows to have multiple frames with only one bullet that is highlighted
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item option 1
        \item option 2
    \end{enumerate}
    \pause
  
    \begin{equation}
        f(x)=a\times x^2+b\times x +c
    \end{equation}
    }
  \end{frame}
  
 

  % Thank you slide
  \begin{frame}[standout]
    Thank you!
  \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. It's working perfectly.

Comment: @zeropoint You're welcome!